# Running scripts with Yarn 2's PnP

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

To run a script with Yarn 2's PnP, one should run `yarn node script.js`, rather than `node script.js`.

Is there an universal way to run things like `ts-node` (i.e. where you don't call `node` directly, thus you can't replace it with `yarn node`) with Yarn 2's PnP?

Answer (score 0):

Just running `yarn ts-node [...]` (or `yarn run ts-node [...]`) works fine.